# How to change column name of Report Viewer report?

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I am using `ASP.NET/C#`.I am using `Report Viewer` control to display a basic report.Currently the data is shown properly however the column names are the same as when selected while configuring the `Report Wizard`.

**Example:**

`cFirstName` is displayed as `cFirstName` in the column header of the `Report Viewer`.

I would want to change it to **First Name** instead.

Here is the image of the issue.

[image]

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this in the rdl, rdlc file.

This is where it should normally be done.

It cannot be done through c#, unless you take that column name as a report parameter and set the column header using that parameter.

Comment: You mean in the design mode?I am not understanding it properly.

Comment: Another thing can I set width of the header columns?Is it possible.Thanks.

Comment: In the rdl designer, you can definitely set the width.

Comment: Sometimes you can't actually set the column name as a non-CLI (such as ## or !@#$%^&*(){} etc )